# TypeScript+Jest - how to use jest.spyOn with generic TypeScript methods?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have the following TypeScript object defined:

```
// HttpClient.ts
export type HttpResponse<T> = Response & {
  data?: T;
}

async function get<T>(url: string, args: RequestInit = {}): Promise<HttpResponse<T>> {
  return fetchRequest<T>(url, {...args, method: 'get'}) // fetchRequest returns value of type Promise<HttpResponse<T>>
}

export default {get} // default export represents an HttpClient object
```

I also have another file, `getFeatureFlag.ts`, that uses this `HttpClient` in its implementation:

```
// getFeatureFlag.ts
import HttpClient from '../httpClient'

export type FetchResponse<T = any, E = any> = {
  data: Nullable<T>;
  error: Nullable<E>;
}

export type FeatureFlag = {
  toggleActive: boolean; // true/false denotes show/hide feature
}

export async function getFeatureFlag(flagName: string): Promise<FetchResponse<boolean, string>> {
  const response = await HttpClient.get<FeatureFlag>(`/v1/toggles/${flagName}/`)

  // ... rest of the implementation ...
}
```

I'm in the process of writing unit tests (using Jest) for this file under `getFeatureFlag.test.ts` and I have the following snippet within it:

```
// getFeatureFlag.test.ts
import HttpClient, {HttpResponse} from '../httpClient'
import {getFeatureFlag, FLAG_STORE, FeatureFlag} from '../index'

describe('getFeatureFlag', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    // vv === THIS LINE IS WHAT THIS POST IS ABOUT === vv
    jest.spyOn<HttpResponse<FeatureFlag>, 'get'>(HttpClient, 'get').mockImplementationOnce(() => ({
      ok: true,
      data: {
        toggleActive: true,
      },
    }))

    result = await getFeatureFlag(flagName)
  })

  it('then perform api request for feature flag data', () => {
    expect(HttpClient.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/v1/toggles/featureFlag/')
  })
})
```

From within the `@types/jest` definitions file, the `spyOn` function is defined as the following:

```
function spyOn<T extends {}, M extends FunctionPropertyNames<Required<T>>>(
        object: T,
        method: M
    ): Required<T>[M] extends (...args: any[]) => any
        ? SpyInstance<ReturnType<Required<T>[M]>, ArgsType<Required<T>[M]>>
        : never;
```

I am having a lot of difficulty getting the TypeScript compiler to correctly read the below snippet without issue.

```
jest.spyOn<HttpResponse<FeatureFlag>, 'get'>(HttpClient, 'get').mockImplementationOnce(() => ({
      ok: true,
      data: {
        toggleActive: true,
      },
    }))
```

With the above setup, the compiler tells me that `get` does not satisfy the constraint `never` and I am at a loss of how to resolve the typing problem here to get my test written/running correctly. The other thing I'm trying to do here is only return a `Partial` of `HttpResponse` because I obviously don't want to have to fill in every field within my unit test when they are not needed.

Has anyone been able to apply `jest.spyOn` correctly with generics to help with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* all you're missing is the word `async` in your call to `mockImplementationOnce()`.  Then you can remove the type params for `jest.spyOn`.  You don't get type safety within your mock implementation automatically, but if you're really worried about it, you can add `as HttpResponse<FeatureFlag>`.

```ts
let result: FetchResponse<boolean, string>;

describe('getFeatureFlag', () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
        //                                                  missing
        //                                                     ↓
        jest.spyOn(HttpClient, 'get').mockImplementationOnce(async () => ({
            ok: true,
            data: {
                toggleActive: true,
            },
        } as HttpResponse<FeatureFlag>));

        result = await getFeatureFlag(flagName);
    })
});
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAEsxgEoQM5gPYDsUQDwBUA+KAXigG8BYAKCjqnQGsAuKAI3XQBsIBDTANw16UACa9gvAPyt8Q6gF95NAMZYUwWPDABhLgEsImTWSq16vFCEwqoAcwjAChABQBXAE5dWGj-sx2ADRQvB52KKzkCqQUCgCUrAAKHugAtvo4uHAIyGjqeETEZiIiHo6emBTCJTVMrMAebhCB1TUi4pKR0ZZQ+K0lSv0KNMPUNKCQUAByblxcvGw8zjH4UAA+UJizXPIT0ABijioAFrkY2AUx-CDBAKJXmCDEpv0dvKwzcwtLRPIiEB4Uh4PttvnhboR5KMIAAPDAeTR7KCHCSeCD7eZ2GLFejAdB2Ow8ACCKmA+gAbhBWBxuHxBCMaDRLNZbAAzNw2MlYeyOFHANEY3h2FyszFTXipKlQXz+OwJKDJNIZPCHYAnM75XA0nj8YIygKEIr9BogKrmGpqbCaMp5C5XADuvH0mmyugMRmAADoHE4+QLMa4AAYAenJAEZg3iCTwUMGACTkUVC8WShSBuJ-NplfkeSrkMQSd5QG3nHCet4AQk9UcJEBJZMpwQBQNYWzmUEG5o7UBUEhOUBczbiZraxfKuYoBc6m22TcB6GBUGbnslKBQQugnZEo1GNGDACp98J971UMBj8GaKIICp5mUe+pNEm7Cmpfq7MpqDxrahZsBWKq6qoKWeDanSeoNLKkKMtQ14oCofhsBALgAOQ+n6ZSCnYKHBC4w4kEaXZIayC4QLcvAnC4zI2AO+GEaOABWZ6emgIAAPKYC4rp6IYxjBGhjgoXEK7oCojAAJKpGAPCSsYEj6FgHEqMh1G2HhpDEC4OKjnQdRQA0TQtF2o5vJE-Q6bi+K1vWFJSgZzTmW0ChGaO3QoFoOTAZqGHogGcQZjBo42n+DpOpo6F8DmvlCiKYoShAAVdvEn4iM6qHAMcRhQJAHgkR4qQhGA+hjgAjk0GhQHllWRWilWYlOvA4bRGkjm0sKQKSXHaDxHreo4wl4jAvCUgAQhARg6LwcwQKIADqzrHKhoYRjWMbBqyNWYZiwZCUMiXJTBB5HrQJ4AFJnvp4DQNet6hPJ6gXjQmDxWgFHQExFXaUucILpoN13tASL7BypIKZgio5aAr4oMsphQAA2gA0lA-hQIwEAgOgrK9AAurISM499wBGKI7kuJ6FOhOErDXPDON0SEjxQFIUDI62ECUh4Hbw+jmPY-ghMAGTSpBASZnQ7W-WIN4AyjxgAqyb1QAAymAIDiVa-DKQQDw3FAACaRMk+5tOE2Q1z0W0qSiRJUkyR692YEpyGspgrDk5TYQRAbDP4PKGUZOLHZB-9oSA1dUBEl7+BXbDvRG5gpMDhTnpU97-gbVzRIM9czOR1A7Oc0H-SSwi0u3fe7KcmD0pqxxOuwsTifuVEwQALIJ0nwPV1gEMAlDL24MgZX6GUojOIaLjoGwTGkrIwSShl6CiKwbfysPbijzNzjw23hON8byee9TjMgHTOdM1Ijl0Kr6uazYeDIDmmAx5AQ8QCPY873vhDBFH4Sv0fh-TeX8iC7xxoaAumwOYAhSvQUumh-DE1ykrNufZMoeBhogS2NRBrDQgGNCaU0eBzQWh7T0YA7qpG9qbdeQddxdgQXLZBitlJQFuHCG8mgvoiB1ubR4rgKL8imrIeUaC1QYJhr8IYDIxiwRlmHSqIMuSVDgghfQSEXDPUlD4UWQR9Jnm9upAiUByToH0KIeUZiLHyFDpXZRNdiKkXIpRV27sGbWMsawTxtiFH2J7pUNK2i3x6OCG45qJjPFWPMaIXxFdoCWgqu1LhrAPpeg4R1YAAggA)

Granted, this doesn't answer the question asked in the title, but it should fix your code.  I messed around for a long time trying to get your specified generic type arguments to work, and eventually gave up.  It *may* be a limitation of the declarations in the `jest` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to change your code like this:

```
jest.spyOn(HttpClient.prototype, 'get').mockImplementationOnce(() => {... return <expectedResultObject>; })
```

This works for me with the *typed-rest-client/RestClient* npm package just like charm:

```
import * as rm from 'typed-rest-client/RestClient';
import {StatusCodes} from 'http-status-codes';

let apiSpy: jest.SpyInstance;

apiSpy = jest.spyOn(rm.RestClient.prototype, 'get');
apiSpy.mockImplementation(path => {
    const response: rm.IRestResponse<string> = {
        statusCode: StatusCodes.OK,
        headers: {},
        result: 'stringResult'
    }
    return response;
})
```